# Dynamic list slicing

Tags: python, algorithm, list, multidimensional-array

Good day code knights,

I have a tricky problem that I cannot see a simple solution for. And the history of the humankind states that there is a simple solution for everything (excluding buying presents)

Here is the problem:

I need an algorithm that takes multidimensional lists and a filter dictionary, processes them and returns lists based on the filters.

For example:

```
Bathymetry ('x', 'y')=(182, 149) #notation for (dimensions)=(size)
Chl  ('time', 'z', 'y', 'x')=(4, 31, 149, 182) 
filters {'x':(0,20), 'y':(3), 'z':(1,2), time:()} #no filter stands for all values
```

Would return:

```
readFrom.variables['Bathymetry'][0:21, 3]    
readFrom.variables['Chl'][:, 1:3, 3, 0:21]
```

I was thinking about a for loop for the dimensions, reading the filters from the filter list but I cannot get my head around actually passing the attributes to the slicing machine.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have a clue what you're doing nor what you want to do. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Got lost in thought. Edited for simplicity.

Comment: I got married and my wife now buys most of the presents.

Comment: @Pete, sound like a hack, bat a solution indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
def doit(nam, filters):
    alldims = []
    for dimname in getDimNames(nam):
      filt = filters.get(dimname, ())
      howmany = len(filt)
      if howmany == 0:
        sliciflt = slice()
      elif howmany == 1:
        sliciflt = filt[0]
      elif howmany in (2, 3):
        sliciflt = slice(*filt)
      else:
        raise RuntimeError("%d items in slice for dim %r (%r)!"
                           % (howmany, dimname, nam))
      alldims.append(sliciflt)


return readFrom.variables[nam][tuple(alldims)]
```

Comment: Aaah, so there IS such a thing as a slice object. Just what I needed, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understood your question. But I think the `slice` object is what you are looking for:

First instead of an empty tuple use None to include all values in time

```
filters=  {'x':(0,20), 'y':(3), 'z':(1,2), 'time':None}
```

Then build a slice dictionary like this:

```
d = dict(
        (k, slice(*v) if isinstance(v, tuple) else slice(v))
        for k, v in filters.iteritems()
    )
```

Here is the output:

```
{
    'y': slice(None, 3, None),
    'x': slice(0, 20, None),
    'z': slice(1, 2, None),
    'time': slice(None, None, None)
}
```

Then you can use the slice objects to extract the range from the list

Comment: Thank you!
Too bad I cannot accept more than I answer. Yours is very elegant while Martellis is easier to understand. Being a newbie I will go for the simpler one.